# Change the name of the _id property in Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

Simple Question 
I have MongoDb and I want to change the name of the `_id` property to make it `MatchId` 
but this does not work. 
It is worth mentioning that all other properties (Except the `_id`) could be renamed,
I have no problem with that

Can the `_id` property be renamed in a BsonElement? 
Or it must have `_id` name and can not be changed? 
I searched the documentation but found nothing

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MatchState>(cm =>
{
    // this does NOT rename the _id property to "MatchId"
    cm.MapIdProperty(x => x.MatchId).SetElementName("MatchId");

    // this DOES rename the "MatchCreator" property to "Creator" property
    cm.MapProperty(x => x.MatchCreator).SetElementName("Creator");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe copy `_id` into `MatchId` is what you need.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "MatchId": "$_id"
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k95pw2AbcGI)

Comment: this will not remove the `_id` and mark the `MatchId` property as Id